# Filling a Matrix With Certain Condition in R

Tags: algorithm, r

Given a matrix of size `M` and `N`, 
we want to fill in each row with integer value (>=0) 
so that it sums up to certain value.

Note that the dimension of `M` and `N` are pre-computed using
certain formula, so that it is guaranteed to match
the fill given the desired condition (i.e. `sum_val` below).

This are two examples

```
#sum_val <-2
#m<-6
#n<-3

# the value of "sum_val" may vary
# and 'm' 'n' also change depends on it

# First are initialized using 0
#mat <- matrix(0,nrow=m,ncol=n);


# Below results are hand coded:
       [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    1    0   # Sum of each rows here is equal to 'sum_val = 2'
[2,]    1    0    1
[3,]    0    1    1
[4,]    2    0    0
[5,]    0    2    0
[6,]    0    0    2
```

Another example:

```
> sum_val<-2;
#m<-15
#n<-5
#mat <- matrix(0,nrow=m,ncol=n);

# Below results are hand coded:
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    1    1    0    0    0   # rows also sums up to 2 
 [2,]    1    0    1    0    0
 [3,]    1    0    0    1    0
 [4,]    1    0    0    0    1
 [5,]    0    1    0    0    1
 [6,]    0    0    1    0    1
 [7,]    0    0    0    1    1
 [8,]    0    1    0    1    0
 [9,]    0    1    1    0    0
[10,]    0    0    1    1    0
[11,]    2    0    0    0    0
[12,]    0    2    0    0    0
[13,]    0    0    2    0    0
[14,]    0    0    0    2    0
[15,]    0    0    0    0    2
```

I'm stuck with the following loop:

```
> for (ri in 1:m) {
+     for (ci in 1:n) {
+      
+        
+        # Not sure how to proceed from here
+        if(ci==2) {
+             mat[ri,ci] <- 1;
+        }
+     }
+ }
```

What's the best way to solve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how I'd solve it!

```
library(partitions)

sum_val <- 2
n <- 5

t(as.matrix(compositions(sum_val, n)))
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 [1,]    2    0    0    0    0
 [2,]    1    1    0    0    0
 [3,]    0    2    0    0    0
 [4,]    1    0    1    0    0
 [5,]    0    1    1    0    0
 [6,]    0    0    2    0    0
 [7,]    1    0    0    1    0
 [8,]    0    1    0    1    0
 [9,]    0    0    1    1    0
[10,]    0    0    0    2    0
[11,]    1    0    0    0    1
[12,]    0    1    0    0    1
[13,]    0    0    1    0    1
[14,]    0    0    0    1    1
[15,]    0    0    0    0    2
```